# Echo variable which has been set in another classes function

Tags: php, class, oop, variables

I am trying to access the contents of a variable from another class. I have the code below, I am expecting to get 'test' returned, I get nothing.

I assume this is because it is getting `$abc_rank` as empty. It is required that the variable is populated in the function itself.

Therefore how can I get `$abc_rank` to hold that echo and output via the other class?

```
<?php

class class1 {

    public static $abc_rank;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->add_text();
    }

    public function add_text() {
        $this->abc_rank = 'test';
    }

}

class class2 {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->display();
    }

    public function display() {
        $test = class1::$abc_rank;
        echo $test; 
    }

}

$go = new class2();

?>
```

I know I can do:

```
public static $abc_rank = 'test';
```

But the population of the variable must be in a function.

I have read some of the other related answers and can't seem to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **class1** :

Replace `$this->abc_rank = 'test';` with `$this::$abc_rank='test';`

($abc_rank is a static property)

In **class2** :

In your display function : replace

```
$test = class1::$abc_rank;
echo $test;
```

with

```
$test = new class1();
echo $test::$abc_rank;
```

(class1 isn't static)

Full code here :

```
class class1 {

    public static $abc_rank;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->add_text();
    }

    public function add_text() {
        //$this->abc_rank = 'test';
        $this::$abc_rank='test';
    }

}

class class2 {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->display();
    }

    public function display() {
        //$test = class1::$abc_rank;
        //echo $test; 
        $test = new class1();
        echo $test::$abc_rank;
    }

}

$go = new class2();
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to create the class1 to run the constructor of this class.

```
class class1 {

    public static $abc_rank;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->add_text();
    }

    public function add_text() {
        self::$abc_rank = 'test';
    }

}

class class2 {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->display();
    }

    public function display() {
        $test = class1::$abc_rank;
        echo $test; 
    }

}
new class1(); 
$go = new class2();
```